# Load file with specific file extension in Android app and make the app default handler for that filetype

Tags: android, file

I am trying to create an Android app, which can load a file with a specific user file extension with the default file browser and I want to define this app as the default app for opening files with that file extension. Therefore a example file can be created.
I have following problems:

- The file browser can not access the directory, which contains the test file
- I can define a initial directory only with StorageManager, which needs at least SDK 29 (but I want to use minSDK 27).
- If I define a file extension filter, no file can be loaded
- Setting the app as default application for the file extension does not work

To see my code look on https://github.com/hobber89/androidOpenSpecificFileType.

Can me please anyone tell me what I have to change, that the app is recognised as default app for the file extension (.test), why the file browser opened from the app can not access the directory, which contains the test file, and how I can let user select only files with that extension.

Kind regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: `The file browser can not access the directory, which contains the test file` Then create your test file in a location where the file browser has access.

Comment: `I can define a initial directory only with StorageManager,` Dont know what you mean by that. But you can create files in all public directories on external storage. Where file managers have access too.

Comment: "that the app is recognised as default app for the file extension (.test)" -- that's not really an option for custom file extensions. "how I can let user select only files with that extension" -- that's also not really an option for custom file extensions. File extension support has never been good on Android.

Comment: "Then create your test file in a location where the file browser has access": the app creates the test file within the directory, which is returned by getExternalFilesDir(). Why can the file browser not access this directory?

Comment: With "I can define a initial directory only with StorageManager" I mean to do something like
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);